# Node Js Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: node.js, azure-cognitive-services

i am having a problem calling Cognitive Services from NodeJs.  i am pretty new with Node so doing a conversion from straight JavaScript to Node has been a challenge.  when i use an image that is on the internet it works, but i need to use an image that is on the local server and have tried many things to meet the requirement of it being a raw binary file.  Here is what I have been trying...

```
    const cognitiveServices = require('cognitive-services');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var apiKey = "myapikey";
    var apiUrl="https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze"
    const FRIENDS_IMAGE_URL ='http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/10/09/636115830685164048-686058602_friends.jpg';

    const parameters ={ "visualFeatures": "Tags","details": "Celebrities","language": "en"}
    //var body = { "url": FRIENDS_IMAGE_URL };

   var body = { "url":  getlocalimage()};
   //var body = getlocalimage();

   function getlocalimage()
    {
      var fn = "test.jpg"
      var base64 = fs.readFileSync(fn).toString('base64');
      //  var myimage = "data:image/jpeg:base64," + base64;
      var myimage =  base64;
      return new Buffer(myimage, 'base64').toString('binary');
     }

    function cogtest()
      {
        const chkImage = new cognitiveServices.computerVision({
                     apiKey: apiKey,
                     endpoint: "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
      })

    chkImage.analyzeImage({  parameters,  body  })
      .then(response => { console.log(response); })
      .catch((err) => { console.log(err);});

      }

       cogtest();
```

Since the call can be made successfully when using an image from the web and the error i keep getting is:

```
   { StatusCodeError: 400 - {"code":"InvalidImageUrl","requestId":"96432967-59d8-4851-a039-1e5b281b4cb7","message":"Can't fetch the image."}
    at new StatusCodeError (/Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
    at /Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:97:41
    at tryCatcher (/Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:606:10)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/Tim/Downloads/0PiNode/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:800:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:762:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:733:5)
  name: 'StatusCodeError',
  statusCode: 400,
  message: '400 - {"code":"InvalidImageUrl","requestId":"96432967-59d8-4851-a039-1e5b281b4cb7","message":"Can\'t fetch the image."}',
  error: 
   { code: 'InvalidImageUrl',
     requestId: '96432967-59d8-4851-a039-1e5b281b4cb7',
     message: 'Can\'t fetch the image.' },
  options: 
   { uri: 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze',
     method: 'POST',
     headers: 
      { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'KEY' },
     qs: 
      { visualFeatures: 'Tags',
        details: 'Celebrities',
        language: 'en' },
     json: true,
```

any ideas?  i believe it has to do with passing a raw binary image in the body.
 Per the module 
https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services

https://github.com/joshbalfour/node-cognitive-services/tree/v0.2.0#computer-vision---analyze-image

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to convert the image to the base64 representation. You can simply do this:

```
var parameters = {
    "visualFeatures": "Tags",
    "details": "Celebrities",
    "language": "en"
}

var body = fs.readFileSync("test.jpg");

var chkImage = new cognitiveServices.computerVision({
    apiKey: "myapikey",
    endpoint: "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"
})

chkImage.analyzeImage({
    parameters,
    body
})
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

I.e., just send over the result of `fs.readFileSync` as the body of the request.

Comment: i tried that but am getting errors..  { StatusCodeError: 400 - {"code":"InvalidImageUrl","requestId":"d031231b-9e35-43f6-959f-2e8556dc7f02","message":"Can't fetch the image."}   i also tried adding const headers = {  "content-type": "application/octet-stream" }; then add it to the chkImage.analyzeImage statement, but also got errors, this time.. { StatusCodeError: 400 - {"code":"InvalidImageFormat","requestId":"e065f813-5aa2-491c-905b-f0a0f4891e72","message":"Input data is not a valid image."}

Comment: The code I posted works for me.. are you sending a valid image file? And less than 4 MB of size? See https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fa for more limitations

Comment: I copied your above code snippet and added only the "require" statements and my key... on a new mac that i just setup node on... i can get the friends.jpg from the web with the code to work.  but if i copy the friends.jpg to my local system and use the readfilesync as in the snippet it still gives me the "InvalidImageUrl" error.  any idea what else it might be?

Comment: not sure if it matters but i am using v9.2.1 node, 0.6.2 cognitive-services all on a mac.  will also test it on my RaspberryPis tonight that is the final location for this code anyway.. will let you know if it works.